# sails.js how to get _csrf to use in vuejs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am using, sails.js to build a REST API. i want to use the first built in template of sails.js.
[sails.js template choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqrvn.png)

I am having issues with authentication. I can't use post man to sign in nor log in.
I searched a bit and I was able to get the _csrf token inside sails with

```html
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>" />
</form>
```

but i couldn't find any route that will deliver me the token as a json so that i can access it form vue.
something like  `GET : localhost:1337/api/token`

```js
{ _csrf: 'ajg4JD(JGdajhLJALHDa' }
```

can someone help get me on track. i have been looking for a while now.

Answer (score 3):

#### For frontend

In your frontend you can access the CSRF on the global object inserted by Sails - `window.SAILS_LOCALS._csrf`.

#### For testing

In your `config/routes.js` you will have to add this:

```
'GET /.temporary/csrf/token/for/tests': { action: 'security/grant-csrf-token' },
```

Do not let this go to production though. The recommended way for this is to only expose this route during automated tests. Here is some info about testing in Sails.js - https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/testing - Here is my `lifecycle.test.js` - https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/63df651dc76812da6cb3bfe1ce4e9e0e - You see I expose this route only for my tests, so my production doesn't get this. It's not recommended to test your endpoints with Postman because those tests are ephemeral, your testing work is now gone after you are done. But if you write unit/integ tests, that work testing will stay forever.

Comment: If you don't use this in production, how do you get your csrf tokens on the frontend in production if you aren't using a frontend built by sails (i.e. a SPA communicated to a sails api)

Comment: @CalebJay this is a good question you should make a new topic about it. A token should be available on `res.locals._csrf`. Just inject it on one of the payloads of a route, as does the action used above - https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/security/csrf/grant-csrf-token.js#L13

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Sails v1

```
// config/security.js
module.exports.security = {
    csrf: true,
};

// config/routes.js
'GET /csrfToken': 'SomeController.grantCsrfToken', 

// api/controllers/SomeController.js
module.exports = {
 grantCsrfToken: function (req, res /*, next */) {
    // Don't grant CSRF tokens over sockets.
    if (req.isSocket) {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        return res.notFound();
      }
      return res.badRequest(new Error('Cannot access CSRF token via socket request.  Instead, send an HTTP request (i.e. XHR) to this endpoint.'));
    }
    // Send the CSRF token wrapped in an object.
    return res.json({
      _csrf: res.locals._csrf
    });
  },
}

// assets/js/some_filename.js
function send_some_post_request(extra_params) {
  $.get("/csrfToken", function (data, jwres) {
    if (jwres != 'success') { return false; }
    msg = {
      extra_params: extra_params,
      _csrf: data._csrf
    };
    $.post("doStuff", msg, function(data, status){
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Why is the action necessary instead of using the built-in `security/grant-csrf-token` action? Other than that you want to block from sending over sockets? I'm also not sure why Noitidart says not to use this in production. I mean, you'd need CSRF tokens in production as well, surely?